# How to use Netlify frontend with Digital Ocean wordpress headless cms with single Google domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, digital-ocean, gatsby, netlify

I have a domain from Google Domains.  It is configured to use the Google Domains name servers.  I created an A and CNAME record pointing to my Netlify site where I'm using Gatsby.

In Netlify, I have my default domain (provided by netlify) Primary domain (the one purchased from google) listed in custom domains settings.

In DigitalOcean I have a One Click Wordpress droplet installed with the domain/subdomain of admin.{mydomain}.com pointing to my droplet.

When I access admin.{mydomain}.com I receive the `This site can't be reached admin.{mydomain}.com's IP address could not be found.` screen.

I can access my digital ocean droplet through the IP address, but when I try to access {ip address}/wp-admin, I'm redirected to {domain}.com/wp-admin which is a default Gatsby Not Found page.

**Where do I need to configure the subdomain of admin.{mydomain}.com to point to my digital ocean droplet and what do I need to configure?**

{mydomain}.com properly renders the site with Netlify.  I can access the main page of the wordpress instance through the ip address on Digital Ocean.

Comment: Matthew, did you solve your problem? If yes what is the way to go, please?

Comment: I can’t quite remember how I solved this.

In digitalocean in my DNS records, they all have the hostname of `admin.{MY_DOMAIN}`. My A record directs to an ip address. And I have 3 NS types that direct to the different digital ocean records.

I can access the wp-login by going to `admin.{MY_DOMAIN}/wp-login.php`

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I finally manage to do it. I did set up a new WordPress droplet on DigitalOcean, then during the installation, I added SSL for admin.my-domain.com and then setup a A record on Netlify to point to my elestic ip of DigitalOcean